# Why is salesforce returning internal server error when I try to render a custom dependent picklist in visual force page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, person-accounts, gack

I have a visual force page which overrides the Edit/New pages in salesforce. But when I create a dependent pickList like so:

1. Navigate to Setup> Customize > Accounts > Fields
2. Scroll down to "Contact Custom Fields & Relationships" section
3. Click on the "Fields Dependencies" button
4. Click on the "New" button (new field dependency creation follows)
5. For "Controlling Field" select "Test Source"
6. For "Dependent Field" select "Test"
7. Continue to end of the process and save Field Dependency
8. Navigate to Setup> Customize > Accounts > Fields > Person Accounts > Page Layouts
9. Edit person account page layout
10. Place both of the dependent fields on the page layout
11. Create new person account

After this I get a internal server error. The funny thing is when I make a dependent picklist for Account Custom Fields & Relationships everything works.

What could be causing this problem?